# CD/DVD drive not showing on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, device-manager

I recently upgraded my laptop to Windows 10 and now CD/DVD drive wouldn't show it on "This PC". A look into Device Manager shows that the device is detected and working properly. However, there's a white question mark icon on it.

**Do note that I am not asking what the question mark means.** I am asking how I can make my CD/DVD drive work under such circumstances. The question is where else can I look for possible reasons that cause it to not work even though Device Manager says it's working. As far as I know, media drives doesn't require drivers and I can't find one for this drive anyway.

[image]

I have already attempted all the resolutions in the following article except for the fixit one. Windows 10 is still not supported.

*[Your CD or DVD drive is not recognized by Windows or other programs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314060)*

Comment: possible duplicate of [What means a blue question mark in Vista/Windows 7 Device Manager](http://superuser.com/questions/228998/what-means-a-blue-question-mark-in-vista-windows-7-device-manager)

Comment: It means the driver is not signed.

Comment: @Moab I'm not asking what the question mark means. I'm asking how can I get windows to recognise the CD/DVD drive and display it in "This PC". Currently I am unable to use the CD/DVD drive as it doesn't show up a all, even when I insert media into that drive.

Comment: @Moab You are linking me something I have already linked and stated that it doesnt work in the question.

Comment: Does the drive show up in disk management?

Comment: @Moab That would be a no.

Comment: I think Widows 10 enforces driver signatures on devices that can play back protected content, [best guess it blocks the device when there is no signed driver.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548231(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Moab I believe that is the case as well. However, the drivers are automatically installed by the device itself. Uninstalling it would just make it  reinstall on the next hardware scan. I cant drivers for it anywhere on the internet. Additionally its a laptop CD drive and thus I am unable to replace the drive. Is there a way to either turn off that feature or make an exception for a driver?

Comment: Its a windows driver included with the OS, which makes me wonder why it is unsigned, strange problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for myself after attempting to solve another issue.

Booting into advanced startup going into startup options provided an option to disable driver signature enforcement. Doing so allowed the unsigned driver to run and thus allowing the drive to work.

Kudos to Moab for finding that it is due to the fact that Windows 10 enforces driver signatures for devices.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following to fix your problem

1. Disable, and then re-enable the device in Device Manager
2. Uninstall and then re-install the driver software for the device
3. Check for possible driver updates in Windows update or Device Manager
4. Test whether or not the problem is present with the same device on a different computer

If the steps listed above fail to solve your problem, I would try to scan your computer for driver updates using [Driverpack solution](http://drp.su/). (I am not affiliated with this product in any way.)

Also, the question mark next to the driver image can mean several things, however I will assume, based on the fact that Windows has not assigned the default "DVD Drive" image to your device, that either your device/driver is incompatible with Windows 10, or that the driver was not installed during the Windows 10 upgrade for another reason.

Comment: The first 3 solution has already been attempted. I am unable to remove the device and refit to another computer without disassembling my laptop. Ill attempt the Driverpack Solution when I have the chance.

Comment: 2) worked for me in a slightly different situation, and in a simpler way: uninstalling (*"Uninstall device"*) and restarting the computer was enough for the driver/device to be reinstalled (I am not sure of the exact terminology).

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading older or newer versions of that CD/DVD drive Driver.

Alternatively, check for phantom and hidden devices in Device Manager. If any show up, uninstall them, then uninstall the non phantom/hidden driver too and start again with a fresh driver installation.

I had to download older trackpad drivers for a new laptop in order for it to work fully so the same may apply here.

Comment: 99% of CD/DVD drivers are generic drivers and included within windows OS. I cant find any specific drivers for this device at all not to say newer or older ones.